# XML trailer value parsing and store in variable in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have a xml file with sample content mentioned below,

How to Fetch the values from trailer node: FileCreationDate, Recordcount and store into a variable in SSIS.

Is it possible without script task?

Can any one help with the list of steps involved?

```
<ACOParticipantData xmlns:xsi="">
  <Header>
    <HeaderCode>HDR_PFPRVDR</HeaderCode>
    <FileCreationDate>20160101</FileCreationDate>
    <ACOProgCode>21</ACOProgCode>
  </Header>
  <Participants>
    <Participant>
      <ACO_ID>V199</ACO_ID>
      <TIN>123456789</TIN>
      <Old_TIN>987654321</Old_TIN>
      <Org_NPI>1234567890</Org_NPI>
      <Ind_NPI>1234567890</Ind_NPI>
      <CCN>123456</CCN>
      <PRG_Eff_Dt>20160101</PRG_Eff_Dt>
      <PRG_Term_Dt>20161231</PRG_Term_Dt>
    </Participant>
  </Participants>
  <Trailer>
    <TrailerCode>TRL_PFPRVDR</TrailerCode>
    <FileCreationDate>20160101</FileCreationDate>
    <RecordCount>1</RecordCount>
  </Trailer>
</ACOParticipantData>
```

Answer (score 0):

An XML Task can be used for this.  Of course some details will need to be adjusted based on your environment and other such factors, but retrieving the values can be done as follows.  The XML Task below will need to be repeated for each variable and XPath, if and possible I'd recommend loading the XML file into a table then using T_SQL XML functions (i.e. `VALUE`) to query this and return all the variables in a single operation.

- Create an XML Task with the XPATH `OpertationType`, File Connection for `SourceType`, and the XML file as the `Source` field.
- In the Output section of the Task Editor, set `SaveOperationResult` to True, `DestinationType` to Variable, and add the variable which will hold the corresponding XML value in the `Destination` field.
- The Second Operand section is where the source statement will be configured.  For the `SecondOperandType` field, either choose Direct Input and enter the XML XPath query or select the Variable option and choose a variable that holds this query.
- To use an XPath that is set dynamically to set `SecondOperationType` to Direct Input and on the Expression page add the variable that will hold the XPath for the `SecondOperand` expression.
- For XPath Options, set `XPathOperation` to Values to retrieve the text from the necessary nodes.